# Importing bulk csv file to oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, import

I am going to import a bulk csv file to oracle database. This file contains around 200m records. I was wondering what is the best way of importing this file? I check the performance of SQL developer and SQL Loader script but both of them was poor in comparison to MS SQL server. In MS SQL server the import wizard takes less than 1 hour for this file but in Oracle I am unable to do that in less than 6-7 hours! So how can I speed up the importing procedure?

SQL Loader command:

```
sqlldr CONTROL=244105_result_20140331_12_07_05_20140331_12_07_05.ctl   skip=1
```

SQL Loader script:

```
load data 
infile '244105_result_20140331_12_07_05_20140331_12_07_05.csv' "str '\n'"
append
into table CDR2
fields terminated by ', '
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( anum CHAR(4000),
             bnum CHAR(4000),
             call_type CHAR(4000),
             call_date CHAR(4000),
             call_time CHAR(4000),
             call_duration CHAR(4000),
             amount CHAR(4000)
           )
```

Comment: What is your control file?  What is your command line?  Are you doing a direct path load?  Are you loading data across the network?  Is the file on the client machine or the server?  Can it be moved to the server?

Comment: CSV file and database are both on the same machine, So network is not bottleneck.  I am using the script generator of sql developr for creating SQL Loader script.

Comment: Does that generate a control file and a command line?  Can you post those?  What is the database waiting on?

Comment: yeah It does. I will add that to question.

Comment: You should use a direct path load done through `OPTIONS (direct=true)` If you don't, those are just "plain" `insert`s

Comment: What you mean? Could you edit the script for me?

Comment: Using direct path (11.2.0.3), I was able to load 236,126,040 rows in approx 17 minutes. Same file split into 5 files (each  about 47m rows), were loaded using external table interface under 6 minutes. So, i am sure you can do some tweaking there . Use direct path load, explore external table option as well.